# How to convert a day and year to a date (last day of the month) in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am trying to  store credit card expiration dates to be able to notify users that their credit card is expiring in the next 30/15/5 days.

Stripe provides the exp_month and exp_year. How do I convert these to a single date field as of the last day of the month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

`Date.new(exp_year, exp_month, -1)`

Example:

```
2.0.0-p247 :009 > Date.new(2014,4,-1)
 => #<Date: 2014-04-30 ((2456778j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
2.0.0-p247 :010 > Date.new(2014,12,-1)
 => #<Date: 2014-12-31 ((2457023j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```